# android: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when i reopen the app after some 5-10 mins

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

In my application i have a listView.

I populated this listView 10 items at a time.

So, i fetch the 1st 10 items in the background when i am showing a spalsh screen. and once the splash screen goes away user can see the 1st 10 items.

Now in the Activity which contains this listView i wrote something like this:

```
onLastItemReached(){
    getNextten();
}
```

works fine. and when i am going to someother activity from this listViewActivity i set the flag so that all the items browsed till then will be retained when back is pressed(i mean if user scrolled down to 100 items and clicked one item and went to some activity and clicks device back button, he will be shown the 100th item and the rest 99 items doesn't need to be fetched again)

the problem is when i close the application and open it after some 5-10 mins it gets crahsed saying:

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

if i am reopening it in 1-3 mins it works fine.

Sorry i cannot post any code because all the activity has around 800 lines.

Any one has any idea why i get this exception always. and 1 thing i want to know is, is there anything like `if an app is in background for more than 5 mins remove all its data`

Edit:

my closing my application, i mean when i am on the ListView Screen i press Home button, reopen the app after 5-10 mins

This is the StackTrace i get, I was trying to Handle unCaughtExceptions:

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020660)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Android.WiC_MobileApp/com.Android.WiC_MobileApp.FeedListViewActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1728)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1747)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
```

So after looking at my log cat it says the error is at line 201, and that line contains:

```
    Log.d("array of product names", SplashActivity.products_array[0] + "--"
            + SplashActivity.products_array[1]);
```

This is an array populated in SplashActivity and made `public static`.

Comment: you won't get any help if you don't post some code

Comment: I think when you come back to your application after 10 minutes or more you lost data.. So first Check for it. whether its available or not.. Its happen when your activity takes more time on stack it will removed bu OS.

Comment: @user370305 yeah even i thought something like what you said makes sense. But by "lost data" you mean the data i fetched in the previos Activity(Splash Activity where i am fetching 1st 10 items in backgraound)?? or the whole application data(all the 100 items scrolled til then)???

Comment: @user370305 please have a look at the last few lines of my edited question. Does this confirm that the data populated in that Array is removes and hence i cant fetch it now??

Comment: Yeah... Never do this... `SplashActivity.products_array[1]` .Don't use static array... As your **SplashActivity** removed from stack you will lost Array... instead it store in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if an app is in background for more than 5 mins remove all its data

This could actually happen within 1 minute.  It's just dependent on the environment that the system is running on.  When you press the home button (or back button on the top activity) the system will put your app in a hibernation sort of mode.  It keeps it in memory until that memory is needed.  This allows the user to quickly go back to it on the event that they simply wanted to switch real quick and go back.  After a few minutes though, if the user opened up a game or something, the OS may decide to wipe the app from memory.  In which case, when the user reopens your app, you have to rebuild everything from scratch.

The reason your app crashes is because you're trying to retrieve the element before the app has actually rebuilt the ListView.  If the app is still in memory, it works because everything is still built.  If the app was removed, then the list must be rebuilt, re-inflated, or whatever.  Then you try to retrieve the element.

Comment: I used the term "data" in my question. But i don't exactly know what data. Is it the data of 1st 10 items i am fetching before the ListViewActivity(in the SplashScreenActivity) is shown? or all the 100 items data fetched till then??

Comment: I don't know the logic that you use, but if you're constantly building the array (i.e., every time the user scrolls you build the array by 10 records), then your index is going to reflect that.  When you return to the app, your array side will be "0".  If you only build it with 10 items at the beginning of the program but you try to retrieve item 99, it won't exist.  Item 99 could now be item 9.

Comment: can you please check the last few lines of the edited question

Comment: Rather than saving the index, it might be better to save an ID number.  That way, you only rebuild the elements that are surrounded by the ID number and figure out it's new index when the array is rebuilt.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Point still stands.  Your array is empty.  This is especially true since you're retrieve the first and second element and getting that error.

Comment: +1 thanks a lot. It solves my problem after changing the logic.

Comment: if i have 20k-30k strings in an array which i will fetch in the background while showing the splash screen, what is the best way to use this array in every activity without getting issues like this. I mean where and how to store this?? storing this in the sqlite database makes it persisten?? i mean can i get data from the database from any activity??

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: You can get access to the database from any activity that falls under the same package name that's declared in the Manifest, so that would be a decent way of storing them.  File I/O may be faster (emphasis on *may*), but could be more restrictive.

Answer (score 2):

When  your app is in the background, Android can kill it at any time (simply by killing the process that your activities are running in). If the user then wants to return to your app, Android creates a new process for your app and then recreates **only the activity that was on the top of the activity stack** (ie: the one that was showing when your app went to the background).

From the logs it looks like your app crashes when trying to launch `FeedListViewActivity`. Since this is probably the activity that was showing when your app went to the background it looks like Android is trying to recreate the activity, which would imply that your process was killed while the app was in the background (see my explanation above).

You say that the data you are trying to access is set up by `SplashActivity` and kept in a static variable. The problem is that when Android creates a new process for you, it only recreates the top activity, not all the activities underneath that. It doesn't recreate the `SplashActivity` so that variable has not yet been initialized.

Here are some possible alternatives to deal with this:

1. Check if the process has been recreated in `onCreate()` of `FeedListViewActivity` and, if so, you'll need to recreate the list of data that the `SplashActivity` had previously set up for you. You can tell if the process has been recreated by having `SplashActivity` set a `public static boolean` variable to `true` when it runs and by checking that variable in `FeedListViewActivity`.
2. Check if the process has been recreated in `onCreate()` of `FeedListViewActivity` and, if so, simply redirect to your `SplashActivity` to start the application all over again.
3. Persist the data by saving it to a Bundle in `onSaveInstanceState()`. Android will call this method on your activity before the process gets killed so you have a chance to save any data you may need later when the activity/process is recreated. You'll need to restore the data in `onCreate()` and/or `onRestoreInstanceState()`.
4. Persist the data in a file or in an SQLlite database.

Comment: if i have 20k-30k strings in an array which i will fetch in the background while showing the splash screen, what is the best way to use this array in every activity without getting issues like this. I mean where and how to store this?? storing this in the sqlite database makes it persisten?? i mean can i get data from the database from any activity??

Comment: Yes, you can store the data in a database and then it is available to any activity. The other choice would be to keep them in memory, but for that you will need a service. Android won't kill a process hosting a service as easily as it will kill a process hosting just activities. However, if it needs the memory it will even kill a process hosting your service and then you're back where you started. If the data doesn't change much I think the database idea might be better. However, I don't know your application or your requirements.

Comment: like you said " If the data doesn't change much I think the database idea might be better ". It might change every day but only few strings will be added like some 100-200. And by " keep them in memory " you mean cache them??

Comment: By "keeping them in memory", I mean that you can keep them in a variable (a list or array or whatever), but you will need to keep them in a variable that is in a service, not an activity. In that case you could do it without the database. That means the service would connect to your server and load the data and keep it in memory and make it available to your activities. If the service is killed, when it restarts it will need to fetch the data again.

Comment: one last doubt. Can i do something like if this Activity Goes to background close the entire application?? So that when the user tries to reopen the application it starts from scratch every time??

Comment: Yes, you can set `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in the manifest for your **root** actvity (in your case the splash screen). This means that every time the app is launched, the task will be cleared and the root activity will be started. However, you can also do something programatically to detect if your process has been killed and just redirect the user back to the splash screen in case the app has been restarted after the process has been killed. You can set a `public static` variable to `true` the first time the app is launched and later check if that variable is set. If not, redirect

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because every time when you reaches to last item you are trying to read 10 more records.

But suppose your array has **50 records**. When you reach to 50 you are again going to read new **10 records**. **it means 51-60**

which are not available that's why you are  getting exception

```
onLastItemReached(){
    if(totalDispayed < yourArray.length())   <-----
    getNextten();
}
```

You need to implement something like as i have mentioned above